# Make application not take over menu bar but still have dock icon?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm making an application that I want to function like a status bar app, where it doesn't control the menu bar (so if it's open over, say, Firefox, the menu is still the one for Firefox), but I also want people to be able to cmd-tab to it for keyboard navigation purposes. I know about Application is Agent, but that only flips both those things at once. Is there some more granular control elsewhere that allows me to change these aspects individually?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using the regular control-F8 and arrow keys for navigating the status menus?

Comment: I suggest you look into hot keys.

Comment: @red_menace the status menu isn't what I'm trying to refocus, the app has a toolbar associated with it. I'd like to be able to cmd-tab back to it while having it still not occupy the menu bar.